# How to copy SKSpriteNode with SKPhysicsBody?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, copy, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I am curious about a situation that I came across today when trying to unarchive and copy a `SKSpriteNode` from one `SKScene` to another. In the output from the playground below you can see that both `linearDamping` and `angularDamping` or not being maintained after the copy (they seem to be dropping back to default values)

```
// PLAYGROUND_SW1.2 - SKSpriteNode Copy
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

// ORIGINAL
let spriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
spriteNode.name = "HAPPY_NODE"
let size = CGSize(width: 55.0, height: 150.0)
let physics = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: size)
physics.linearDamping = 0.123
physics.angularDamping = 0.456
spriteNode.physicsBody = physics

// COPY
let spriteCopy = spriteNode.copy() as! SKSpriteNode

// ORIGINAL
spriteNode.name
spriteNode.physicsBody?.linearDamping
spriteNode.physicsBody?.angularDamping
spriteNode.physicsBody?.area

// COPY
spriteCopy.name
spriteCopy.physicsBody?.linearDamping
spriteCopy.physicsBody?.angularDamping
spriteCopy.physicsBody?.area
```

PLAYGROUND OUTPUT
[image]

I am not sure that I am copying this correctly, both `SKSpriteNode` and `SKPhysicsBody` conform to `NSCopying` If you look at the output above the `area` property is maintained after the copy and to my knowledge this is based on the `size` specified when the `SKPhysicsBody` was created.

Can anyone cast some light on this and maybe provide me with a pointer as to how I should be deep copying an `SKSpriteNode`?

Comment: Looks like a possible bug. [Have you filed one](http://bugreport.apple.com)? Have you tried separately copying the physics body?

Comment: Hi, I will try doing the physics Body copy and then submit a bug report if that fails too. I had not reported it yet because I wanted to make sure I was not missing something obvious before wasting Apples time. Much appreciated Sir.

Comment: If i create just a single SKPhysicsBody and try and copy it (I am using a playground) I get a SIGABRT, so something is definitely not right here. I will search the Apple site and submit a bug.

Comment: As no one other than Rickster has commented I have done as he suggests and filed a bug with Apple #20003803

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I take one way to resolve your problem, probably is not the best way, but

```
   //COPY
   let spriteCopy = spriteNode.copy() as SKSpriteNode
   let physicsCopy:SKPhysicsBody = spriteNode.physicsBody!;

   ...
   //COPY PHYSICS BODY HARD MODE
   spriteCopy.physicsBody = physicsCopy;
```

To fix this problem, I created one extension, and @mogelbuster suggested override default `copy()`, ant it sounds great.

```
extension SKSpriteNode
{
    override open func copy() -> Any {
        let node = super.copy() as! SKSpriteNode;
        node.physicsBody = super.physicsBody;
        return node;
    }
}
```

With this extension you can do it, the default `copy()` method return `Any` because this you need cast to `SKSpriteNode`.

```
// COPY
let spriteCopy = spriteNode.copy() as! SKSpriteNode;

// ORIGINAL
spriteNode.name
spriteNode.physicsBody?.linearDamping
spriteNode.physicsBody?.angularDamping
spriteNode.physicsBody?.area


// COPY
spriteCopy.name
spriteCopy.physicsBody?.linearDamping
spriteCopy.physicsBody?.angularDamping
spriteCopy.physicsBody?.area
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer!  An extension on SKSpriteNode is definitely the way to go.  Would it be better to override the original `copy()` method and call `super`'s implementation (like in initializers) instead of making a new `copyWithPhysicsBody()` method?

Comment: @mogelbuster I changed the answer based on your tip. It is a nice observation, I liked this change. Thank you for the observation.

Comment: @Fattie You wouldnt want to do this anyway, this doesn't copy the `SKPhysicsBody`, it just assigns the copy node's physics body to the existing `SKPhysicsBody`, which I am guessing would either crash, or leave the original without a `SKPhysicsBody`

Comment: i guess the guy's original three lines of code (right up the top) will really copy it - but yeah  :/  By "does not work" I meant "does not copy the property values" as (I guess) you'd expect them to have had NSCopy do here ...

Comment: You're not supposed to override properties/functions in swift extensions, you should read the docs.

Comment: `node.physicsBody = super.physicsBody;` causes runtime error in Swift 5.3; changed to `node.physicsBody = super.physicsBody?.copy() as? SKPhysicsBody` worked.